# Multiple sources found for csv : readStream

Tags: eclipse, scala, csv, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am trying to run below code to read file as a dataframe onto a Kafka topic (for Spark Streaming), developed via Eclipse IDE, using Scala, defining schemas appropriately, by running thin jar on server using spark-submit (without invoking any additional packages) and am getting error below. Tried out suggestions from researching on internet based on `spark.read.option.schema.csv` similar errors with no success.

Has anybody encountered similar issue for Spark Streaming when using readStream option??

Looking forward to hear your response(s)!

**Error:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Multiple sources found for csv (com.databricks.spark.csv.DefaultSource15, org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat), please specify the fully qualified class name.
```

**Code:**

```
val csvdf = spark.readStream.option("sep", ",").schema(userSchema).csv("server_path") //does not resolve error
val csvdf = spark.readStream.option("sep", ",").schema(userSchema).format("com.databricks.spark.csv").csv("server_path") //does not resolve error
val csvdf = spark.readStream.option("sep", ",").schema(userSchema).csv("server_path") //does not resolve error
val csvdf = spark.readStream.option("sep", ",").schema(userSchema).format("org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv").csv("server_path") //does not resolve error
val csvdf = spark.readStream.option("sep", ",").schema(userSchema).format("org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat").csv("server_path") //does not resolve error
val csvdf = spark.readStream.option("sep", ",").schema(userSchema).format("com.databricks.spark.csv.DefaultSource15").csv("server_path") //does not resolve error
```

Comment: Please add a "small" sample of the input data and show how userSchema is defined.

Comment: Data is :                                                                                                                               1,Nightmare Before Christmas,1993,3.9,4568
2,The Mummy,1932,3.5,4388
3,Orphans of the Storm,1921,3.2,9062
4,The Object of Beauty,1991,2.8,6150
with schema defined in code as                                                                             val userSchema = StructType(Array(StructField("id", StringType), StructField("name", StringType), StructField("year", StringType), StructField("rating", StringType), StructField("duration", StringType)))

Comment: Please put your new information into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Pom.xml did not have spark-csv jar called explicitly.

Turns out server HDP path containing jars for Spark2 had both spark-csv and spark-sql jars, that was causing the issue of conflicting sources for Csv.
On removing the extra spark-csv jar from the path, issue got resolved.